# Design pattern for managing queues and stacks?

Tags: design-patterns

Is there a design pattern for managing a queue or a stack? For example, we are looking to manage a list of tasks. These tasks will be added to a group queue, users will then be able to pull off the queue and add them to their personal queue.

Comment: "Managing a queue or a stack" can mean just about anything. What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: A Queue is a Design Pattern.  So's a Task.    What are you asking?

Comment: By task, I mean a unit of work, in this case it's a business object.

Comment: So that's your design pattern: Task (or Unit of Work).  What more do you need?  You have some design patterns.  What's the question?

Comment: Search for Queue-based Load Leveling Pattern

Answer (score 6):

Design patterns can *use* [queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29) and [stacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29), but the queues and stacks themselves don't really implement a design pattern, they implement an interface.

Queues are typically [FIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_%28computing%29) while stacks are [LIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_%28computing%29).

Since many users might be using the data structures simultaneously, you should use proper [synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29) to avoid concurrency issues.

Are you looking for [concurrency-related design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_pattern) to use?

Answer (score 1):

Most frameworks provide some kind of queue and/or stack implementations. E.g. in .NET - System.Collections.Generic.Queue and System.Collections.Generic.Stack