# What is the opposite of a Dispatcher pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, software-design

A dispatcher delegate work to other objects but is there a pattern for when objects take work if on a stack? I'm trying to have a group of threaded objects check a shared stack for input where if one object is free, it would grab the next untaken input from the stack to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consult [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703095/design-pattern-for-managing-queues-and-stacks), which would argue that Queues (which is really what you're describing) are just stacks, which is a fair argument.

The basic pattern is pretty much exactly what you describe: a stack that holds a heap of work that workers will grab from when they become available.

In the wild, you might see this pattern frequently:

- A queue is built from a stack.
- The service will contain a `next()` method that will return the next piece of work and mark it as unavailable.
- The service will also contain a `complete()` method that will remove the item from the stack.

The importance of the `next()` vs `complete()` is that sometimes errors occur, and if you don't have the two step process, work might be lost. You'll see this in most queue services, although it isn't strictly necessary.